# Display Products on Home Page with Pagination in Magento

Tags: magento, pagination

I am new to magento.
I am creating a products page which will contain large number of products.

I am trying to display them on my **CMS** page, But i am able to show only **20 records** per page. I just want to show **pagination**, So that user can navigate through the products easily.

I have searched over the net and found this code and updated in **Layout Update XML**

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

But it's not working.

Are there any default **paging mechanisms** in Magento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i found the solution for my question

here **Layout Update XML**

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="home" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>

<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
 </block>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name><count>5</count></action>
</block>
 </reference>
```

just change category **id** you want to paginate.

Comment: Great! I've put it in my layout\local.xml between tags <cms_index_index>...</cms_index_index> and it magically work, thanks